# Virus Scanner that does nothing

Tags: windows, antivirus

I have many virtual machines which I use seldomly. On these machines I started disabling Windows Defender, because it will use a lot of resources when I turn on a VM after a month or two.

When I do that, Windows shows an annoying red X for virus protection. This red X takes precedence over other notifications.

[image: Windows showing a red X]

So I'd need a fake virus scanner which does nothing and thus has no impact on performance, except that it registers as a virus scanner so that the red cross goes away.

I'd pay 10 EUR for a personal license which I can use on as many VMs as I like.